# Is it possible to trigger a notification in another android phone using broadcastreceiver?

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver

I'm new in android development, and need some help and guidance in triggering my notification in my application. I manage to read some documentation about BroadcastReceiver where in it broadcast an announcement and another app can receive that announcement and trigger something to happen(like popping out a notification). I tried doing it, wherein I have **2 (two)** application in **1 (one)** android device and it worked. But when I try separate the **2 (two)** application and install it separately into **2 (two)** android device and try to send the broadcast, the receiver didn't manage to receive the broadcast. Then I tried to do more research and saw that `BroadcastReceiver` is a "System-Wide" broadcast, means (correct me if I'm wrong) it will only work inside **1 (one)** android device. So my question is now, is there anyway to make the `BroadcastReceiver` send the broadcast in the network so that if an android device with a receiver can receive the sent broadcast? if it's not possible, is there another way to trigger notification in 1 device using another device w/o using the FCM/GCM?

**PS:**
*The reason why I don't want to use FCM/GCM is that I'm trying to do this in an adhoc network, wherein internet connection is not present. And I'm not sure how FCM/GCM will behave w/o the internet connection. I appreciate any help. Thanks you.*

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a server in a background service on one of the devices and send data to if from the other device, and then have that service create a notification when it gets data.

If you want the devices to automatically be able to discover each other try using the network discovery service. https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html

Comment: how can I setup a server in the background? can you please provide a sample tutorial on how this thing is done?